# App is crashing when I am using firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance() in Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, build.gradle

I am working on a simple login app using firebase authentication, Whenever I click button for the Signup button(which is using firebase), the app crashes. I tried multiple ways in android studio with changing versions of firebase auth, kotlin and targeted sdk but nothing worked for me.
One thing I noticed that if I remove the line :
`firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`
the Signup page started opening, According to me there is a problem in using firebase. Is there any way why this happens again and again in android studio?
Actual code is following:

```
package com.example.poemworld

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.poemworld.databinding.ActivitySignupBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignupBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup) // Remove this line

        // Initialize binding
        binding = ActivitySignupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

         //Initialize Firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        // Use binding to access views
        binding.materialButton.setOnClickListener {
            val emailValue = binding.email.text.toString()
            val passwordValue = binding.pw.text.toString()
            val userValue = binding.username.text.toString()
            val fullnameVal = binding.name.text.toString()

            if (emailValue.isNotEmpty() && passwordValue.isNotEmpty() && userValue.isNotEmpty() && fullnameVal.isNotEmpty()) {
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailValue, passwordValue).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        val intent = Intent(this, Motivation::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Registration failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incomplete Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.backtologin)
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            val intent1 = Intent(this, loginfile::class.java)
            startActivity(intent1)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried bunch of things like updating sdk/ changing version of kotlin and adding the dependencies in gradle but nothing worked. Please Guide on this issue because I am dealing this with few days and still it is not resolved form any of the resourses.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate() method, initialize the FirebaseAuth instance.

Replace

**firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()**

with

// Initialize Firebase Auth

**firebaseAuth = Firebase.auth**

and try once